# Cryptographically secure and unique string in PHP

Tags: php, security

I've been using

```
$string = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)) . uniqid();
```

Because I need some string that is both crytopgrahically secure and unique. Question is: is this a naive approach? By using the result of uniqid() tacked onto the end of the string,am I giving away any information that might compromise the security of the string? I ask this because uniqid() is based on system time, and my concern is whether that could give any information away that allows an attacker to guess future outputs?

Thanks

Comment: If your goal is cryptographically secure, just use `random_bytes()`. [OpenSSL may not be a good choice](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/96). We have a polyfill library available for `random_bytes()` at [paragonie/random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you tacking uniqid to it? why not just use the first function?

With 16 bytes, there are about 34 followed by 38 zeros possibilities. For almost any application, the risk of collision is negligible. I would stick to just

```
bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16))
```

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php):

> If you need a cryptographically secure value, consider using
>   random_int(), random_bytes(), or openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()

Answer (score 2):

You should use one from the following to generate crytopgrahically secure unique string/number,

1. `bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16, TRUE));` // [Refer manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) - (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7)
2. `bin2hex(random_bytes(16));` // [Refer manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) - (PHP 7)
3. If you want to generate random number, you can use `random_int(100, 999)` // [Refer manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) - (PHP 7)